# Has the Russian Federation received any meaningful help from China or North Korea other than political statements against US/NATO/EU?

Tags: russian-federation, china, armed-conflict, ukraine, north-korea

1. Ukraine has been receiving at least some help from various countries. I have read about many countries are sending gear and weapons to Ukraine.
2. Almost every country is supporting Ukraine morally. People are coming out on street, protesting against Russia, social media support, and so on and so forth.
3. China and North Korea blamed the US/NATO.
4. Seems at the moment the only country supporting Russia to win the war is Belarus.

---

Has China or North Korea provided help to Russia other than speaking against the US or NATO?

Comment: Not even rhetoric, really. China at least has been a bit guarded in statements on Ukraine.

Comment: The propaganda mill is certainly at work inside China.  Public opinion in China is being molded to support something.

Comment: It is not clear whether the question is about the conflict between Ukraine and Russia (in which case the *enemy* is incorrectly defined) or about the political standoff between Russia and US, NATO, EU (which is itself too vaguely defined to say who is on which side).

Comment: I have cleaned to question in an effort to prevent its closure. I hope it is clearer now. @Gary2 - feel free to (partially) revert my edit if needed.

Comment: Is this question only about China and North Korea or would help from other countrie count as well?

Comment: Disagree with point 2, it should be Almost every western country is supporting Ukraine.

Answer (score 13):

China, India and UAE opened their doors (created demand) for Russian goods (supply) that was sanctioned by EU and US. Ironically, the reason China and other countries were able to do so, is that EU NEEDS the supply of gas and oil that they sanctioned, so now they buy the same supply from China at a marked up price, similar to how Ukraine "gained independence" from "Russian gas" by continuing to transit Russian gas to Europe, then buying that same gas from Europe via a reversed pipe.

What we have today, is - Russia diverted their EU supply into China, India and UAE. China, India and UAE get more income for basically transiting Russian gas and oil to EU, and the only clear loser is EU who buy the same supply but at a marked up price.

This response was very quiet and received little coverage, but very valuable to Russia (as in - negates sanctions, prevents a crippled economy), and also benefits China, India and UAE.

EDIT: Sources for the China case:
[US Oil Imports](https://tradingeconomics.com/united-states/imports-of-crude-oil) and [US Oil Exports](https://tradingeconomics.com/united-states/exports-of-crude-oil) rose in February 2022, mostly tankers from China, and exports to Canada. Approximately the same time as [China and India soaked up Russian oil exports](https://www.spglobal.com/commodityinsights/en/market-insights/latest-news/oil/061522-russia-seaborne-oil-exports-at-3-year-highs-despite-sanctions-shake-up)

**Sources:**

1. [Fujairah benefits from uptick in Russian crude transiting](https://www.spglobal.com/commodityinsights/en/market-insights/latest-news/oil/070122-fujairah-benefits-from-uptick-in-russian-crude-transiting-to-the-bunkering-storage-hub)
2. [Abu Dhabi crude to head to Europe](https://www.reuters.com/business/energy/frances-totalenergies-ship-abu-dhabi-crude-europe-rare-move-sources-2022-04-25/)
3. [Saudi Arabia doubles oil imports from Russia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yB2U9wGDL9Y)

Comment: Do you have any sources for this? Considering crude oil, for which seaborne deliveries are more significant, the decrease in Russian imports seems to have been made up by increase in Middle Eastern, African and American imports. Chinese and Indian supply appears to be negligible.

Comment: @CharlieEvans I posted a couple of articles, maybe later I will add some links to graphs, showing that UAE hasn't increased oil production significantly, but imports and exports have grown. Combined, this basically means - if UAE isn't producing more oil, but it is importing and exporting more oil, then it's just transiting Russian oil to EU. One of the articles clearly states that part of the transit is going to Asia (India and China). Like I said - poor coverage, but with (a lot) of between-the-lines, and numbers analysis, the picture is quite clear.

Comment: @MishaP The articles do not support your central contention. One discusses a shipment of oil from the UAE to Europe, the other discusses transit of Russian oil to India via the UAE. The picture is far from "clear". In any case, I still see no evidence of transit via China or India.

Comment: @CharlieEvans I will add more sources later. As I said - coverage is minimal, so it took quite a bit of accidentally found information to put this together.

Comment: The have been some observation that Russian oil may be processed into something else and that resold, hiding the true origin. But the U-bent oil pipes (to China, then back and now legal to sell in Europe) read like really crazy. Do you actually have sources for that? In the list of sources you give  I do not see these histories.

Comment: There's no U-pipe Russia->China->Europe. There's transit of Russia->China->US->Canada

Comment: It's unclear how you come to the conclusion that US Oil imports in February were mostly increased by Chinese tankers. I don't see a breakdown by country of origin in the source you've linked. Data from the US Energy Information Administration for non-OPEC imports can be found [here](https://www.eia.gov/totalenergy/data/monthly/pdf/sec3_11.pdf). China is not a sufficiently major supplier to have its own listing. Note that imports from Russia *are* listed, so it's unclear why Chinese transit would be necessary.

Answer (score 7):

[According](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-62804825) to Western intelligence, yes. North Korea has sold Russia millions of artillery shells and rockets during this year, seemingly to make up for production shortfalls in Russia itself, relative to the demands of the fighting. (Mind you, there's no claim these were provided gratis.)

> According to declassified intelligence obtained by the New York Times, Russia has bought millions of artillery shells and rockets from Pyongyang.

There's little detail to those claims provided in the press, though. And both North Korea and Russia [denied](https://www.rferl.org/a/russia-north-korea-munitions/32046271.html) any such NK to Russia ammo exports took place or are even envisaged.

As I don't see this mentioned in other answers, the same report mentions Iran selling military drones to Russia. Those have been somewhat better documented with photos of visits to Iranian [shows](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/08/29/politics/russia-iranian-drones/index.html) and seemingly cargo [transports](https://www.washingtonpost.com/national-security/2022/08/29/iran-drones-russia-ukraine-war/) from Iran,
but I've not seen reports of them downed in the field in Ukraine, for instance.

According to LA Times, Russia has acknowledged that North Korea [has](https://www.latimes.com/world-nation/story/2022-09-01/north-korea-workers-russian-occupied-east-ukraine) offered workers to rebuild the Donbas:

> Russian Deputy Prime Minister Marat Khusnullin has said that North Korean construction companies have already offered to help rebuild war-torn areas in the Donbas and that North Korean workers would be welcomed if they came.

The Guardian comments/claims [that](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/sep/06/russia-buying-millions-rockets-shells-north-korea-us-intelligence-ukraine) would be in

> breach of a UN resolution that required member states to repatriate all North Korean workers from their soil by 2019.

Comment: There were also some claims in Western media about North Korea sending 100000 of their soldiers to suport Russia in Ukraine, but turned to be false.

Comment: @convert: I've not seen those.

Comment: Here such sorce: https://www.newsmax.com/newsfront/north-korea-russia-ukraine/2022/08/08/id/1082189/

Comment: @convert: well, besides the dubious source re-reporting it,the claim is that some Russian pundit claimed that on Russian TV. The latters seems to be true, as others seem to have reported that the Russian TV figure said that https://www.businessinsider.com/north-korea-offering-russia-100k-troops-help-beat-ukraine-reports-2022-8 And in any case, he claimed that NK *offered* those troops, not that they were sent. (Besides, Russian TV being full of disinformation is nothing new.)

Comment: Posibly this sorce could be more reliable: https://www.eutimes.net/2022/08/north-korea-may-send-100000-troops-to-ukraine-to-help-russia/

Comment: It seems North Korea has also offered to send people to help rebuild the occupied area according to the source I read. https://apnews.com/article/russia-ukraine-north-korea-government-and-politics-495e976d1217d38c397a16e79cc305de

Answer (score 0):

These two countries are not similar.

China has [a lot of trading](https://www.census.gov/foreign-trade/balance/c5700.html) with USA, much more than with Russia, and is [careful](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.nytimes.com/2022/06/29/business/chinese-companies-russia-sanctions.amp.html) not to get sanctions itself. Not joining sanctions and maybe one another warm word to Russia is probably the most it can afford. They do not sell to Russia electronics that contains sanctioned components from USA (apart few punished violations by private companies). Forget the weapons.

North Korea has little to lose so why not and this is happening.